# Odds / Probability of two things occuring

Tags: statistics, probability, game-development

I'm trying to determine the odds or probability of two things happening.  I know the odds of each but don't know how to combine them.

The first occurrence is 1:25

The second is 1:75

How do I calculate the odds of the first occurrence and the second occurrence both happening?

It's for Bingo. The odds of someone winning bingo on one of 3 predetermined numbers AND having the win also occur on one of 75 predetermined numbers.  This is for a 75 number bingo game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a nice article I found explaining the ins and outs of your question :

http://www.statisticshowto.com/how-to-find-the-probability-of-two-events-occurring-together/

In short, to obtain the odds of two events happening together, you multiply them :

1/25 * 1/75 = 0.04 * 0.01333 = 0.00005333 = 1/1875

Unfortunately, I don't think you have your basic maths right. The probability of having a bingo (I assume you mean a coverall?) isn't 1:25 at all. 1:25 is the probability of drawing a single number from a pool of 25 numbers.

The probability of getting a bingo, drawing from a pool of 75 balls, with a 5x5 card (that has a FREE number) depends on the number of balls drawn. For example, if you draw 24 balls, you have a 0.00000000000000000004 chance of getting a bingo (1:250 000 000 000 000 000). If you draw another ball (raising the balls drawn count to 25), you now have a probability of 0.00000000000000000097 of getting a bingo (~ 1:1 030 927 835 051 546).

You would have about 1:25 (0.0377429329773532) chance of getting a bingo if you draw 67 balls from a pool of 75 with a 5x5 card.

Comment: I think I had the math right but let me explain further I appreciate your help.  A 75 ball bingo game.  there are three "Power Balls" offered.  these are 3 predetermined numbers from the 75 possible.  If a player wins the bingo on one of these three numbers they win the "Power Ball" = 1:25 ? There is a 2nd promotion running concurrently where the player has one predetermined number from the 75 possible.  If the player wins the bingo on this number he wins the promo =  1:75 ?  I'm trying to determine the odds of a player winning both promotions at the same time.  ~  thanks again

Comment: One more clarification.  I'm not trying to figure the odds of the initial bingo win.  Just the odds of the winner winning the promotions.  Odds that someone will win the regular bingo in our case is 100%.  thanks